# SQL select where repeating, but distinct on another column

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the following table:

```
uid | key | email
-----------------
1   |  1  | test@test.com
2   |  2  | test@test.com
3   |  3  | test@test.com
4   |  4  | test@test.com
5   |  4  | test@test.com
6   |  4  | test@test.com
7   |  6  | abce@test.com
8   |  7  | defg@test.com
```

I'd like to grab all of the rows with distinct key but repeating email values

the result should look like:

```
uid | key | email
-----------------
1   |  1  | test@test.com
2   |  2  | test@test.com
3   |  3  | test@test.com
```

Comment: By "Distinct key" do you mean where there is only one occurence in the table of that key.  In your example, would the query return the rows for keys 1,2,3,6, and 7?

Comment: no, because a repeating email, but the key is also repeated and 7 is not repeated anywhere.

Comment: oops.. no because uid 6 has a repeating email, but the key is also repeated.. and 7 has no repetition anywhere.

Comment: I think you need to explain the query a bit more clearly - and give your table a name (a common omission in SQL questions on SO).  The important part is characterizing what it is about uids 4, 5, and 6 that means you don't want to see those rows in the result.

Comment: This question is still incredibly vague about what you are looking for. I guess your acceptance of an answer, however, lets us reverse engineer the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT MIN(uid) as uid, key, email
FROM Keys k INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT email FROM KEYS GROUP by email HAVING COUNT(email) > 1 ) k2
    ON k.email = k2.email
GROUP BY key, email
HAVING COUNT(key) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE email NOT IN
(
SELECT email 
FROM table GROUP BY email
HAVING COUNT(email) <= 1)
AND key IN
(
SELECT key
FROM table
GROUP BY key
HAVING COUNT(key) = 1 
)
```